# Extract values after certain string with Google Sheets

Tags: html, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to extract the values that come after the word 'rawValue=' in the following text with a Google Sheet REGEX formula, so not a script.

> nowrap;" rawValue="-18245000000">18,245</div><div id="Y_5"
> class="pos" style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;"
> rawValue="19916000000">19,916</div><div id="Y_6" class="pos"
> style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;"
> rawValue="20350000000">20,350</div></div><div id="data_i25"
> class="rf_crow" style="display:none"><div id="Y_1" class="pos"
> style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;"
> rawValue="—">—</div><div id="Y_2" class="pos"
> style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;"
> rawValue="—">—</div><div id="Y_3"

The variations that follow 'rawValue=' are fourfold:

- a large positive number: 19916000000
- a large negative number: -18245000000
- a small number: 0
- the words mdash or nbsp, in the example above: mdash

The examples above are also the preferable output form.

How would I be able to extract all these cases? Good to know is that the amount of instances of rawValues in a cell varies. So it should work regardless of how many matches there are, if that's even possible..

Can anyone help me with this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2; 
 "(rawValue="".+)"); "rawValue="""; 0); "^([^""]+)"))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for responding so quick. I can't get the formula get to work when I copy paste it.. May I share a google sheet with you so you can apply it there maybe? Or can you share a sheet with me? By the way, the dashes in the example are actually presented as the word 'mdash' in my sheet. I think it was modified here by someone.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gjYV7H4yW6CzfeIYWOKg-aWdZwVSBC9jRebSQESVz3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Leachim answer updated try now

Comment: When I copy paste the formula and adjust the cellnumber I get this: The value (rawValue = ". +) For Parameter 2 of function REGEXEXTRACT does not match the value... Could you apply in the sheet I linked? Or is that not allowed?https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gjYV7H4yW6CzfeIYWOKg-aWdZwVSBC9jRebSQESVz3M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Leachim https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NFyD3zvVjT0GT453tx_lN_wGmN1rtl6onqIAJ_nZUE4/edit#gid=2056118841

Comment: thanks a lot, it works like a charm! One last thing if I may ask, I see that in my original example above the backslashes are missing after rawValue. How would the formula go if the targettext was made up like this: rawValue=\"9785000000\" instead of rawValue="9785000000"? I'm now using SUBSTITUTE to remove the \ to get the preferred output with your formula. But maybe it can be put into your original formula. Thanks a lot for this!

Comment: it would be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjreD.png